# .NET Stream CopyTo bug?

Tags: .net, filestream, streamreader

I have a bunch of CSV files, all of which have a header line as the very first line of the file.
I need to merge all of those CSV files in a single file, only copying the header once and keeping it as the very first line of the merged file.

I wrote the following code:

```
public static void Merge( string outputFile, params string[] inputFiles )
{
    if( inputFiles == null || inputFiles.Length <= 1 ) return;

    using( Stream outputStream = new FileStream( outputFile,
        FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None ) )
    {
        for( int i = 0; i < inputFiles.Length; i++ )
        {
            var inputFile = inputFiles[ i ];

            using( var inputStream = File.OpenRead( inputFile ) )
            using( var textReader = new StreamReader( inputStream ) )
            {
                if( i != 0 )
                    textReader.ReadLine();

                textReader.BaseStream.CopyTo( outputStream );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code above correctly skips the first line of each file (except the first file which is copied to output entirely), but **fails to write correctly the second line of each file** (roughly  the first half of the second line of each file is missing) and then from the third line it works as intended.

Seems like an issue with the position of the stream or a bug in the CopyTo method.. any idea?

P.S: the problem is very easily solvable with the following code, but i really want to know what's the problem with the code above. Thanks.

```
public static void Merge( string outputFile, string inputDir, string filtro )
{
    if( String.IsNullOrEmpty( filtro ) )
        filtro = "*.*";

    var inputFiles = Directory.GetFiles( inputDir, filtro );

    using( FileStream outputStream = new FileStream( outputFile,
        FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None ) )
    {
        using( var sw = new StreamWriter( outputStream ) )
        {
            for( int i = 0; i < inputFiles.Length; i++ )
            {
                var inputFile = inputFiles[ i ];

                using( var inputStream = File.OpenRead( inputFile ) )
                using( var textReader = new StreamReader( inputStream ) )
                {
                    if( i != 0 && textReader.BaseStream.Position != textReader.BaseStream.Length )
                        textReader.ReadLine();

                    while( textReader.BaseStream.Position != textReader.BaseStream.Length )
                        sw.WriteLine( textReader.ReadLine() );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that you've constructed a StreamReader on top of your basestream and use this to read the first line. However, a StreamReader has a [buffer](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs,69) inside to avoid reading 1 character/byte at the time from the underlying stream. So StreamReader will actually read more from the underlying stream than the first line only and then afterwards when you bypass the reader and read from the stream, you simply continue where filling that buffer left off, most likely in the middle of some line.

Comment: You might also want to google the phrase `SELECT isn't broken`. The chances that you've uncovered a *glaring bug* in a core framework component is miniscule compared to the likelihood that you've made a mistake in *your* code.

Comment: I would instead use the bottom example of code, and rewrite the core loop to be something like `foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(inputFile).Skip(1)) sw.WriteLine(line);`

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Or possibly just use `File.AppendAllLines` and get rid of `sw` entirely...

Comment: @JonSkeet Agreed, and I'm already working on an answer with that in mind

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever i never really thought of a bug: i wanted people to be interested in my question to find a answer. thanks

Comment: @MauroSampietro: That sounds remarkably like click-bait then. If you don't think there's a bug in the framework, please don't *imply* that you think there is one.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Now I get where problem originate from, thanks. Anyway I would expect the buffer of the underneath stream not to interfere with what i'm doing in that way. Ok you internally read more than i ask, but  is it possible to keep track of what i actually read? Perhaps it is much more complicated and i'm oversimplifying...

Comment: @JonSkeet Streams here do not behave the way i would expect. Writing this in the title would have been less catchy

Comment: @MauroSampietro: I don't believe it's anything to do with streams themselves - it's StreamReader that's buffering. But again, I would encourage you to focus on accurate rather than "catchy". If you don't believe there's a bug, then implying that you do in your title is dishonest, frankly. Writing a summary of what you're actually asking about would have been a much better title IMO.

Comment: @MauroSampietro: " Anyway I would expect the buffer of the underneath stream not to interfere with what i'm doing in that way." It's not the buffer of the *stream* - it's the buffer of the `StreamReader`, which has already *read* from the stream. It's really important to distinguish between the stream and the reader here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224360/discussion-between-jon-skeet-and-mauro-sampietro).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is one of buffering.

Your use of StreamReader to skip 1 line will actually skip more than 1 line, unless you're *extremely lucky*.

If you check the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs,69) you'll see that StreamReader uses a buffer, and will try to fill the buffer when needed. It is thus highly likely that it grabs more than just to the end of the current line. If the first lines of your file(s) is very short, it is also likely the first buffer read may grab quite a few lines from the start of your file. The default buffer size seems to be 1024 or 4096 for the reference source, depending on your framework type and version.

Then, afterwards, when you bypass the reader and uses the underlying stream, it will be positioned after the last buffer read that the reader made. That's why it starts in the middle of some line.

Now, there are various ways to do that you want but you can rewrite the whole thing to a lazily evaluated LINQ query and get rid of all of your code.

```
public static void Merge( string outputFile, string inputDir, string filtro )
{
    if( String.IsNullOrEmpty( filtro ) )
        filtro = "*.*";

    var inputFiles = Directory.GetFiles( inputDir, filtro );
    File.AppendAllLines(outputFile, inputFiles
        .SelectMany((inputFile, index) =>
            File.ReadLines(inputFile).Skip(index == 0 ? 0 : 1)));
}
```